# Selenium IDE test duration

Tags: selenium-ide, duration

I was wondering how I can get an echo of the duration of a test.

I already got the time stamp at the beginning of the test and at the end, but for the reason of laziness it would be nice to get an echo displaying the time it took to run the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storeEval` is your friend here.

I'm assuming you have the start and end timestamps stored in variables, so you can storeEval end-start and echo the result

Comment: I did storeEval | ${time} - ${timeend} | duration. 
It always gives me: [error] Threw an exception: invalid label

what did I do wrong?

Comment: looks good, are you sure time and timeend have values in them?

Comment: yes. when I echo them I get e.g. "10 : 51 : 53" or "10 : 7 : 14" for single digit values.

Comment: Ah theres the issue. You should be getting the timestamp in epoch time so you can subtract it.  Technically 10:51:53 is a string, not a number.  If you do storeEval | new Date().getTime(); | a  & echo | ${a} you will see it in number format.  Just set your start and end times using that function, then you will be able to subtract them

Comment: when I do that I get 1364484594151

Comment: yes, thats fine.  if you do storeEval | new Date.getTime() | time, and then your test and then storeEval | new Date.getTime() | timeend, you will be able to subtract them as in your first comment.  The result is the number of milliseconds your test took.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code that works on my side. It displays 5 sec duration (pause in test). Try it yourself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://www.google.com.ua/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>{new Date()}</td>
<td>Cur_time</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>${Cur_time}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>pause</td>
<td>5000</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>{new Date()}</td>
<td>Cur_time2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>${Cur_time2}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>{(storedVars["Cur_time2"].getTime() - storedVars["Cur_time"].getTime())/1000}</td>
<td>diff</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>${diff}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```